# Finding the number of $2017$-digit numbers with leading digit $2$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N$ be the number of $2017$-digit numbers such that the leading digit is $2$ and there are an odd number of $9$'s. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000.$

---

I first jumped to the thought of using some form of casework on the number of $9$'s and trying to find a pattern. Because it is given that the leading digit is $2,$ there are $2016$ digits where you wish to place the $9$'s and the other digits. If there is a singular $9,$ then there are $$\binom{2016}{1} \cdot 9^{2015}$$ possible numbers; if there are three $9$'s, then there are $$\binom{2016}{3} \cdot 9^{2013}$$ possible numbers, and so on. Therefore, I came to the conclusion that $$N = \sum_{n = 0}^{1007} \binom{2016}{2n + 1} \cdot 9^{2015 - 2n}.$$ However, I am unsure how to calculate this large sum, and I was also wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this problem.

EDIT: According to Wolfram Alpha, the answer is $672,$ although I was looking for a method to do this without calculators.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got
$$N = \sum_{n = 0}^{1007} \binom{2016}{2n + 1} \cdot 9^{2015 - 2n}$$

By the binomial theorem, we have
$$(1+x)^m=\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2n}x^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor(m-1)/2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\tag1$$
and
$$(1-x)^m=\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2n}x^{2n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor (m-1)/2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}\tag2$$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor (m-1)/2\rfloor}\binom{m}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}=\frac 12\bigg((1+x)^m-(1-x)^m\bigg)$$

So, when $m=2016$ and $x=\dfrac 19$, we obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor (2016-1)/2\rfloor}\binom{2016}{2n+1}\cdot 9^{-2n-1}=\frac 12\bigg(\bigg(1+\frac 19\bigg)^{2016}-\bigg(1-\frac 19\bigg)^{2016}\bigg)$$

Multiplying the both sides by $9^{2016}$, we have

$$\begin{align}N=\sum_{n=0}^{1007}\binom{2016}{2n+1}\cdot 9^{2015-2n}&=\frac{9^{2016}}{2}\bigg(\bigg(1+\frac 19\bigg)^{2016}-\bigg(1-\frac 19\bigg)^{2016}\bigg)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(10^{2016}-8^{2016}\bigg)
\\\\&=5\cdot 10^{2015}-4\cdot 8^{2015}\end{align}$$

Using Euler's theorem,
$$2^{\varphi(5^3)}\equiv 2^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{5^3}\implies 2^{103}\equiv 8\pmod{1000}$$
so we have
$$8^{2015}\equiv (2^{103})^{58}\cdot 2^{71}\equiv 8^{58}\cdot 2^{71}\equiv (2^{103})^2\cdot (2^{10})^{3}\cdot 2^9\equiv 64\cdot 824\cdot 512\equiv 832\pmod{1000}$$

Therefore, we finally get
$$N=\sum_{n=0}^{1007}\binom{2016}{2n+1}\cdot 9^{2015-2n}\equiv 0-4\cdot 832\equiv \color{red}{672}\pmod{1000}$$